# Losing context reference

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am encountering a 'small' problem when making a new object in the options page.

In the options page I create a few objects and save them as general settings. These objects have method to communicate with different API's. But as soon as I get one of those objects to work with, I lose the context on the page I am.

For example:

The options page I create an object that has a method 'request' and I send an ajax request to some api with this method. When I call this on an other page the ajax request is logged within the options page. When I close the options page I lose all context of the logs it makes.

Is there a way to force the context reference to the current page? or did I make a mistake with creating objects on the wrong pages/saving them and retrieving them on a page that needs them? (IE Should I only save the data I need to create objects on the page itself? (which seems like alot of overhead for the the same thing(?)).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have an option page which creates an Object lets call it MyApi. I create a new MyApi and store it in chrome.storage.local . When a user has some text selected and clicks on the context menu I open a new page(selectedText.html) which shows the selected text and some API calls are made, which are mostly ajax requests. The moment I get the object from storage in selectedText.html and make any request with MyApi I see no logs in the network tab of the ajax requests, neither any console logs. But with my options page open I see everything in there.

**EDIT2**

```
save : function()
{
    var obj = {'api':this.data};
    chrome.storage.local.set(obj,function() { if(chrome.runtime.lastError) console.warn(chrome.runtime.lastError); });
}
```

This is in the background script.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achive, but it is obvious that the context of the options page is no fit for the purpose. Have you looked into **chrome.storage** ?

Comment: I create objects and save them into chrome.storage. but when any methods called it has no console to log anything to.

Comment: There is always a console (of course you have to open it). It is stiil unclear what you mean. Try posting some code and a more detailed explanation of what's happening in each step.

Comment: Hopefully my edit clarifies it a bit.

Comment: I still don't get how you are able to store an Object with methods in **chrome.storage** and then retrieve it (I can't do this). In any case, if you want to have an object with "utility" methods, I would suggest placing it in the background page and calling it from any other page (using **chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()**).

Comment: I store objects as following (see edit)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40914/discussion-between-expertsystem-and-john)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve what you want this way:

1. Define your object/function/whatever in the background page.
2. Use **[chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage)** to get a hold on the background pages `window` object.
3. Execute the desired method, passing as argument an object of the local context. (Of course you have to modify the function to accept and make use of such an argument.)

Example:

**In background.js:**

```
function myFunc(winObj, msg) {
    winObj.console.log(msg);
}
```

**In otherPage.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
    bgPage.myFunc(window, "This will be logged in 'otherPage.html' !");
});
```

It is not the cleanest solution, but it might work...

Comment: This won't work if an ajax call is made on the background page. It will log into the network tab for the background pages which by passes my ajaxSend and ajaxComplete events on the page I am (but are triggered for the backgroundpages).

Comment: The trick is not to trigger it in the context of the background page. Since I kow you want to use jQuery's `.ajax()`, you could pass your content script's `jQuery` object (and any other necessary argument) and just have the function "instrument" everything for you.